# Error when installing Nodemon - cb() never called

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I have tried a few times to install nodemon and it continues to produce the same error. I have re-installed Node.js twice without this fixing the issue. I am running macOS version 10.14.3.

Install commands I have tried:

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
nom install nodemon
```

Here is the error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'nodemon' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose npm-session 5016b457090df714
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon 129ms
8 silly pacote tag manifest for nodemon@latest fetched in 139ms
9 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 247ms
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 1ms
13 silly install loadShrinkwrap
14 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 46ms
15 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
16 silly resolveWithNewModule nodemon@1.18.10 checking installable status
17 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar 30ms (from cache)
18 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 31ms (from cache)
19 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color 30ms (from cache)
20 silly pacote range manifest for chokidar@^2.1.0 fetched in 35ms
21 silly resolveWithNewModule chokidar@2.1.2 checking installable status
22 silly pacote range manifest for debug@^3.1.0 fetched in 34ms
23 silly resolveWithNewModule debug@3.2.6 checking installable status
24 silly pacote range manifest for supports-color@^5.2.0 fetched in 32ms
25 silly resolveWithNewModule supports-color@5.5.0 checking installable status
26 timing npm Completed in 619ms
27 error cb() never called!
28 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
29 error <https://npm.community>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by re-installing node from https://nodejs.org/en/download/. Re-installing from home-brew did not fix the issue.